# Что означают буквы внутри числовых переменных?

Tags: java

Например 
float f = 5,67f;
Что значит эта f (и прочие подобные буквы в числах) внутри переменной?

Comment: `double d = 5.67;
float f = 5.67f;`
`f` определяет, является ли дробное число `double`, или `float`

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это возмутительно.

Answer (score 4):

Числа с плавающей точкой по умолчанию являются значениями типа double. При включении значения типа float в программу за числом следует поставить символ f или F (дополнительно явно указать тип):

```
double d = 6.23;
float f = 6.23f;
```

Числа типа double можно тоже обозначать суффиксом d или D, но это особо не имеет смысла, так как вещественные числа всегда по умолчанию double.

По умолчанию все целые числа интерпретируются как десятичные и относятся к типу int. Символы l или L обозначают числа типа long:

```
long l = 34564L;
```

Символ 0x (или 0X) обозначает шестнадцатеричную запись числа:

```
int h = 0xFF;
```

Восьмиричные значения обозначаются ведущим нулем (обычные десятичные числа не могут иметь ведущий нуль):

```
int oct = 07;
```

Для двоичной системы счисления используют префикс 0b или 0B:

```
int b = 0b1010;
```

Для указания экспоненциальной функции используют символ E или e, за которыми следует десятичное число (положительное или отрицательное):

```
double d = 5.07E12;
```

Также возможна запись шестнадцатиричных чисел с плавающей точкой. В этом случае вместо E используется P (или p):

```
double h = 0x14.3P2;
```